# VSCode C++ c_cpp_properties.json "defines" does not define the symbol on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have a `main.cpp` thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
#if defined(_LINDEBUG)
#if defined(VSCODE)
    printf("VSCODE defined"\n);
#else
    printf("VSCODE not defined\n");
#endif
#endif
}
```

My `c_cpp_properties.json` file in `.vscode/` folder is thus:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${default}"
            ],
            "defines": ["VSCODE"],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ]
}
```

I compile and link this via `make` thus:

```
g++ -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp   -c -g -D_LINDEBUG -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/main.o ../src/main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++ -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/linux build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/main.o  -lm -lpthread -ldl
```

I expected `VSCODE` to be defined via the `.json` file. `_LINDEBUG` is defined via the `make` compilation as `-D_LINDEBUG`. The net effect is that the output is:

`VSCODE not defined`.

Is there a way to define some macros via `c_cpp_properties.json` file instead of via the `make` argument?

---

`tasks.json` is:

```
{
            "label": "lindbgbuild",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "CONF=Debug",
                "-C",
                "./.vscode"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
}
```

`Makefile` exits in `.vscode\` folder that calls `Makefile-Debug.mk` that contains the actual `g++ ...` commands.

Comment: I've only just started using VSCode and copied your `c_cpp_properties.json` file as a template because I also wanted to add a define. Didn't work but noticed a parse error - it is missing the trailing `]` from the `configurations` array!

Comment: @DaveGriffiths Yes, I have been sloppy in not adding the trailing `]`. Fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation [[link]](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference):

> `defines` A list of preprocessor definitions for the IntelliSense engine
> to use while parsing files. Optionally, use = to set a value, for
> example VERSION=1.

So, it seems that you would only add some defines there for the sake of helping out the Intellisense engine. Some quick testing could not get the defines from the c_cpp_properties.json file to be embedded into the code. My guess is that the option exists to help write code when you only have a portion of the project on your machine.

For what it's worth, you are not defining `_LINDEBUG` via make. It is a compiler flag [[link]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). More specifically, it defines whatever name as a macro and gives it a value of 1. The documentation did not state where those definitions are placed.

If what you pasted are the contents of your makefile, you would be better served by learning to create a proper makefile, or take it up a level and learn to use a build tool like cmake.

EDIT: Per your comment, it would just be a matter of adding the arguments to your build task if you want VS Code to define them.

Comment: `you are not defining _LINDEBUG via make` . If there is `-D_XYZ` as the compiler argument then both `#ifdef _XYZ` and `#if defined(_XYZ)` in my code would evaluate to `true`. I may have been sloppy with my wording but indeed `_XYZ` is being defined within my makefile. I don't manually write my makefiles. I use Netbeans IDE on ubuntu to do that work and simply use those for VSCode.